# Ping and Install applications for multiple PCs

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I hope someone can help me with the following script:
The script I built works for 1 computer.  It asks the user to enter the computer name, and It will check if the computer is ONLINE, if it is it will copy and install the application.

Now, I want to add another functionality.  I want users to create a TXT file with all the computer names (line by line) and save them somewhere in the computer.  The user will run the script, and a Windows Explorer would open requesting the location of the TXT file.  So, the script will collect that data (I might be wrong, but should I use arrays for that?)  From there, I am assuming a **ForEach** statement should do it right?

The most difficult (for me) part is... if the computer is OFFLINE, it will skip that computer, and go for the next one... when it reaches the end of the lines, it should go back to the first line and check if the computer (that was offline) is online.  The tricky part is... if the computer already has the app installed, it should skip it, and continue to keep pinging computers and so on.  I want the script to run until someone manually stops it, installed the app to all the pcs, or runs for 3 days.

This might be too much to ask, but... it would also be nice to see a report of all the computers where the app was successfully installed (I am sure this should be on the ForEACH portion).

Thank you all

```
function HarvesterMenu {

$PCName = read-host -Prompt "Enter the computer name"
$PCName = $PCName -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' '
$pingPC = Test-Connection -ComputerName $PCName -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($pingPC -eq $True) {
    Write-host "ONLINE"
    harvesterInstall($PCName)
}
else {
    Write-host "OFFLINE"
}
}

function HarvesterInstall($InstallOnPC) {
    
    $Sourcefile = "\\SERVER1\discovery03$\HarvesterRemote.msi"
    Copy-Item -Path $Sourcefile -Destination "\\$InstallOnPC\c$\windows\temp\HarvesterRemote.msi"
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $InstallOnPC -ScriptBlock {
        Start-Process c:\windows\temp\HarvesterRemote.msi -ArgumentList "/quiet" -Wait
    }
    Start-Sleep 3

    $InstCompleted = Test-Path -Path '\\$InstallOnPC\C$\Program Files (x86)\Labs\Harvester Remote\Harvester\Harvester.exe'

    Write-Host $InstCompleted
    if ($InstCompleted -eq $True) {
        Write-host "Harvester was successfuly installed on $InstallOnPC"
    }
    else {
        Write-host "Something went wrong.  Ping the server and try again"
    }
    
    $BacktoMenu = read-host -Prompt "Press Y to go back to the Main Menu or N to exist"
    if ($backtoMenu -eq "y") {
        harvesterMenu
    }
    else {
        Exit
    }
}

HarvesterMenu
```

Comment: This should be like 3 or 4 separated questions.

Comment: I concur with Santi. Can you also tag the appropriate PowerShell tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily with a Foreach-Loop.

U need a File with the pc's u wanna install the application. maybe .txt or .csv
Then u can just address it in a foreach.

something like that:

```
$InputFile = 'C:\Temp\lIST.csv'
$addresses = get-content $InputFile     
        foreach($address in $addresses) {
                if (test-Connection -ComputerName $address -Count 1 -Quiet ) {  
                    write-Host "$address Online"

                    #ur harvesterinstall

                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                    Write-Warning "$address Offline"

                    }  
        }
```